# Optimal buffer size for output stream

Tags: java, optimization

I'm writing a method to save an input stream to an output stream. What's the optimal size for the buffer? Here's my method:

```
/**
* Saves the given InputStream to a file at the destination. Does not check whether the destination exists.
*
* @param inputStream
* @param destination
* @throws FileNotFoundException
* @throws IOException
*/
public static void saveInputStream(InputStream inputStream, File outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2097152]; //This is set to two MB. But I have no idea whether this is optimal
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on a lot of factors, there's no universally "optimal" size. 512kB is probably good enough.

If you want, you can always benchmark it for various buffer sizes: this will let you know what the best option is for your computer and OS.

Comment: Just asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484115/get-system-block-size-in-java) about getting the block size. Could be useful. But I think you're right :)

Comment: You still should benchmark it. You'll be surprised by the results!